# How to Highlight Dates in Jquery Date Picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to Highlight some Days in the JQuery Date picker, so i have tried out some scripts my result is on Codepen.io. But I cant find the Error why the Dates or not Highlighted.

https://codepen.io/flipitart/pen/vawENB

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // An array of dates
    var eventDates = {};
    eventDates[ new Date( '12/08/2018' )] = new Date( '12/08/2018' );
    eventDates[ new Date( '12/06/2014' )] = new Date( '12/06/2014' );
    eventDates[ new Date( '12/20/2014' )] = new Date( '12/20/2014' );
    eventDates[ new Date( '12/25/2014' )] = new Date( '12/25/2014' );

    // datepicker
    jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
            var highlight = eventDates[date];
            if( highlight ) {
                 return [true, "event", highlight];
            } else {
                 return [true, '', ''];
            }
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple mistakes that were made in this CodePen.

It looks like code that was pasted from different places without understanding some basics.

The **first** was to have some code inside **AND** outside the *Ready wrapper* to instantiate a datepicker on the same element. Since DatePicker already was instanciated by the code outside, the code inside was not applyed at all. You had to place your additionnal datepicker parameters at the same place, which is in between the object passed as argument: `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ -- HERE -- });`

The **second** is an weird usage of an object where the keys are the same as the values... Just to later check if it exists. Why not store a simple date array?

The **last** is about how to compare the dates that datepicker uses and the dates in the array.
**And that is the interesting question here**.

The [`beforeShowDay`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option is a function that loops all the date to currently render. So on "draw" of the current month, it loops through all the 28~31 days of the mont **AND** the couple days before and after.

During that loop, you want to check if a date is in the array of the dates you wish to hightlight. The [`.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method is a good choice to determine this. The thing is to compare apples with apples... The date has to be formated the same way has in your `eventDates` array.

```
var dateToCompare = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", date);
```

This line will format each date from the datepicker loop from a date object to a `dd/mm/yy` string.

Then check if that date is in your eventDates` array:

```
if( $.inArray(dateToCompare,eventDates) >-1 ) {
```

It return a `true` if the date is found. Now remember we are in a loop. We have to [return an a array of 3 values to datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay), which are:

1. Selectable date (true/false)
2. A class name to add
3. A tooltip

You tried this: `return [true, "event", highlight];`. okay for the 2 first values... But  `highlight` is a date object and a string is expected here.

Here is a working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var eventDates = [
    "12/08/2018",
    "12/06/2014",
    "2/20/2014",
    "12/25/2014"
  ]
  console.log(eventDates);

  // Datepicker instantiation
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function( date ) {

      var dateToCompare = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", date);
      //console.log(dateToCompare);

      if( $.inArray(dateToCompare,eventDates) >-1 ) {
        console.log("A date from the array was FOUND.")
        return [true, "event",'This date is in the array!'];
      } else {
        return [true, '', ''];
      }
    },

    firstDay: 1,
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right"></i>',
    onSelect: function() {
      var dateText = $.datepicker.formatDate("MM dd, yy", $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
      $('p.bgText').text(dateText);
    }
  });  // End Datepicker instantiation


  // On load "layout" formattings 
  //
  //getting today's date
  var currentDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd, yy', new Date());
  $('#monthAndDate').text(currentDate);

  //setting bgText to current Date
  $('p.bgText').text("Select a date");

  var currentWeekday = $.datepicker.formatDate('DD', new Date());
  $('#dayOfWeek').text(currentWeekday);

});  //End ready
```

The [**CodePen updated**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KBLwNy?editors=0111).